# How to get the average of values for one column based on another column value in python (pandas, jupyter)

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

[the image shows the test dataset I am using to verify if the right averages are being calculated.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PB5cB.png)

I want to be able to get the average of the corresponding values in the 'G' column based on the filtered values in the 'T' column.

So I set the values for the 'T' column based on which I want to sum the values in the 'G' column and then divide the total by the count to get an average, which is appended to a variable.
however the average is not correctly calculated. see below
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SagHy.png)

```
total=0
g_avg=[]
output=[]
counter=0
for i, row in df_new.iterrows():
    if (row['T'] > 2):
        counter+=1
        total+=row['G']
    if (counter != 0 and row['T']==10):
        g_avg.append(total/counter)
        counter = 0
        total = 0
        
print(g_avg)
```

below is a better set of data as there is repetition in the 'T' values so I would need a counter in order to get my average for the G values when the T value is in a certain range i.e. from 2am to 10 am etc
[sorry it wont allow me to just paste the dataset so ive took a snippy of it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JTk2.png)

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) including data. column `"T"` does not appear to have any value that is `10`, so you are never even entering the second `if`. You can also just use `df_new[df_new['T'] > 2]['G'].mean()`

Comment: @sim It wont allow my to paste in the data set but I have uploaded the code.

Comment: @sim basically the gist of the program is that the dataset but consist of 1 week of data we want to take the average of the 'g' column whenever the 'T' column is for example between 2-7pm and append this to a list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the average of column *G* values when *T* is between 2 and 7:

```
df_new.loc[(df_new['T']>2) & (df_new['T']<7), 'G'].mean()
```

**Update**

It's difficult to know exactly what you want without any expected output. If you have some data that looks like this:

```
print(df)                                                              
    T  G
0   0  0
1   0  0
2   1  0
3   2  1
4   3  3
5   4  0
6   5  4
7   6  5
8   7  0
9   8  6
10  9  7
```

And you want something like this:

```
print(df)                                                              
    T  G
0   0  0
1   0  0
2   1  0
3   2  1
4   3  3
5   4  3
6   5  3
7   6  3
8   7  0
9   8  6
10  9  7
```

Then you could use **boolean indexing** and [`DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
avg = df.loc[(df['T']>2) & (df['T']<7), 'G'].mean()
df.loc[(df['T']>2) & (df['T']<7), 'G'] = avg
```

---

```
print(df)                                                                               
    T    G
0   0  0.0
1   0  0.0
2   1  0.0
3   2  1.0
4   3  3.0
5   4  3.0
6   5  3.0
7   6  3.0
8   7  0.0
9   8  6.0
10  9  7.0
```

**Update 2**

If you have some sample data:

```
print(df)                                                                               
    T  G
0   0  1
1   2  2
2   3  3
3   3  1
4   3  2
5  10  4
6   2  5
7   2  5
8   2  5
9  10  5
```

**Method 1:** To simply get a list of those means, you could create groups for your interval and filter on `m`:

```
m = df['T'].between(0,5,inclusive=False)
g = m.ne(m.shift()).cumsum()[m]
lst = df.groupby(g).mean()['G'].tolist()
```

---

```
print(lst)                                                                              
[2.0, 5.0]
```

---

**Method 2:** If you want to include these means at their respective T values, then you could do this instead:

```
m = df['T'].between(0,5,inclusive=False)
g = m.ne(m.shift()).cumsum()
df['G_new'] = df.groupby(g)['G'].transform('mean')
```

---

```
print(df)                                                                               
    T  G  G_new
0   0  1      1
1   2  2      2
2   3  3      2
3   3  1      2
4   3  2      2
5  10  4      4
6   2  5      5
7   2  5      5
8   2  5      5
9  10  5      5
```

Comment: yes but I don't want one average, I want to append the average to a list each time the t value is between that range. for example the t is the time (2-7am) so this will be repeated again and again over a week period therefore I want to append the average each time this is true to a list

Comment: I've updated the response. Let me know if this answers your question.

Comment: Yes this is correct but it only solves part of the problem (probably du to my vague explanation). the 'T' value will have repeating values for example t=[0,2,3,3,3,10,2,2,2,10] and g=[1,2,3,1,2,4,5,5,5,5]. in this case say I want to take the avg of 'G' values when 'T' is >0 &<5 for each instance this is true I would want to append the avg value to a list. so the list in this case would look like g_avg=[2,5]. this is the part im stuck on. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: I've updated the answer to satisfy this example. Is this what you're looking for?